# How do I change my account settings to install as administrator?

Tags: windows-7

I recently reinstalled Windows, transitioning from 7 Ultimate to 7 Pro (not sure if that will be relevant). On the clean install, when I run installers for certain programs (TeamViewer, in the image below), I am presented with the following dialog:

[image: the error dialog I get]

The user Andrew is a full admin according to the User Accounts window, but does not seem to have permission to install anything that runs as a service. How do I give my account that permission?

Comment: You're not on a domain, are you?

Comment: I'm not - this is a single user home install.

Comment: Is the Andrew account password protected? I know sometimes blank passwords are not permitted.

Comment: It *is* password protected - it's the account I made during the install, which is Admin by default and requires a password.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to place the error message screen shot that you get when you choose Andrew account and its corresponding credentials for program installation?

Comment: Sorry for not responding to this sooner. I can post examples of errors I get in specific programs when I select Current User, but I'm confused as to why that's relevant. I want this dialog to never appear for this user - it never has before on my previous installs of Windows. It should not be asking for credentials at all.